# Race condition with the parallel package in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, vectorization, race-condition, critical-section

I am trying to execute a function with side effect on a vector in parallel. For example, in the following snippet, `add.entry` has the side effect of modifying `master`.

```
library(parallel)

master <- data.frame()

add.entry <- function(x) {
  row <- data.frame(a = x, b = sin(x))
  master <- rbind(master, row)
}

mclapply(1:42, add.entry)
```

The output I get is

> [[1]]   a        b 1 1 0.841471
>
> [[2]]   a         b 1 2 0.9092974
>
> [[3]]   a       b 1 3 0.14112
>
> [[4]]   a          b 1 4 -0.7568025

However, `master` contains nothing afterwards. My best guess is that there is some race condition involved. How can I fix it, like maybe declaring a critical section?

Comment: Your function is not modifying master. For example, try `add.entry(1)` and then print master. It will not be changed.

Comment: @lmo That's interesting... Executing the statements directly does add a row to `master` though. Any idea about what's going on?

Comment: In a functional programming paradigm, functions that modify objects through side effects is discouraged. The master object in the function is local to the function. R does offer a tool to do this with `<<-`. I tend to avoid this tool. You can always use the output of the list to compose the data.frame.

Comment: @lmo I'll take your advice. However, the result given by `sapply(1:4, add.entry)` is transposed, i.e. `a` and `b` are made rows, but I want them to be columns. Maybe I can just use `t` to transpose it again.

Answer (score 1):

1. it is very slow to grow an object inside a loop (cf. https://privefl.github.io/blog/why-loops-are-slow-in-r/).
2. when you use parallelism, you don't `rbind()` to the `master` in your global environment, but to some copies of it in your different forks (cf. https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/).
3. `mclapply` already returns something (like `lapply`).

You can simply do

```
library(parallel)

add.entry <- function(x) {
  data.frame(a = x, b = sin(x))
}

res_list <- mclapply(1:42, add.entry)
master <- do.call("rbind", res_list)
```